# How to check that a user is Admin in SharePoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, csom

How can I check that the current user is a SiteCollection Administrator using SharePoint CSOM?

Comment: You'd need to clarify your question a bit. Are you trying to identify any of the following:

Site Collection Administrator,
Users with Full Permissions on current Web,
Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
spcontext.current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin
```

Answer (score 9):

### How to determine whether current user is Site Administrator using CSOM

**SharePoint 2013 CSOM**

Use [User.IsSiteAdmin property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user.issiteadmin%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to get or set a Boolean value that specifies whether the user is a site collection administrator, for example:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var currentUser = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
    ctx.Load(currentUser);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(currentUser.IsSiteAdmin);
}
```

**SharePoint 2010 CSOM**

Since `User` object does not expose `IsSiteAdmin` property in SharePoint 2010 CSOM, below is demonstrated how to determine whether current user is Site Administrator using `User Information List`:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
     var currentUser = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
     ctx.Load(currentUser);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     var isCurrentUserSiteAdmin = IsUserSiteAdmin(ctx, currentUser.Id);
}


public static bool IsUserSiteAdmin(ClientContext ctx,int userId)
{
   var userInfoList = ctx.Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList;
   var item = userInfoList.GetItemById(userId);
   ctx.Load(item);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   return (bool)item["IsSiteAdmin"];
}
```

Comment: Just a remark: Your App needs fullcontrol-permissions to do this. Otherwise you would not be able to retrieve that information (it will always be false), even if you use the users permission to get the data

Comment: @Vadim Gremyachev : Is there a possibility to determine if the user has SPAdmin permissions via AD  ? We have the problem that if the user has SiteCollection privileges via AD-Groups the SiteAdmin parameter stays false.